# Issues on Apache when sharing files in between docker and Mac OS X

Tags: apache, docker

I am using `Docker version 1.10.1` on my Mac OS X `El Captain`. I created a Docker with CentOS 6 distribution and just installed PHP and Apache. I use this docker to develop my PHP codes.

When I start the Docker I use the parameter "-v" to share the directories. It works completely fine. The Apache and PHP work like a charm.

But.. As I said, I use this docker to develop some codes... So the files are always being changing. For some strange reason, Apache sometimes doesn't recognize it.

For example... Suppose that I use some IDE to edit the file "index.html", the change is saved and I confirm that looking inside the docker. But Apache not recognize this change (even if I restart the apache or the docker!)... But, If I go inside the docker and open and just save the file with "vi" the apache recognize the changed that was made previously.

I checked the date between docker and mac os and it's it pretty the same.

I thought that would be a cache problem in Apache, but I added the following rules in my virtualhost without success:

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Any idea to how fix that? Anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker on OS X uses VirtualBox and VirtualBox doesn't work well with sendfile. You can disable sendfile in your [apache config](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#enablesendfile):

```
EnableSendfile Off
```

Comment: Why is this not documented anywhere?? I debugged for HOURS and found no mention of this. Also, I'm on Windows 7.